# How to completely remove "Install Additional Tools for Node.js" windows10

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I just installed node 12. By mistake I installed all the python things and now having trouble to get rid of it. It's like a malware ...

I tried to remove from Environment variable, Programs and Features

```
npm -g uninstall node-gyp
```

But it's still stick to my start menu as a malware that only good antivirus software can remove ... 
[image]

What do I missing? 
What else I should do in order to get rid of this malware..?? I can't use the angular cli

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Just run cmd as admin and type `choco uninstall all`
You can also check what is installed `choco list -l`

Comment: this is not a good answer if they use chocolatey for other things.

Answer (score 2):

I too clicked on the checkbox by accident. It is indeed annoying!

Here is the line which installs the unwanted tools:

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Start-Process '%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString(''https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'')); choco upgrade -y python2 visualstudio2017-workload-vctools; Read-Host ''Type ENTER to exit'' ' -Verb RunAs
```

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/tools/msvs/install_tools/install_tools.bat

I could uninstall the tools again manually in the *Apps & Tools* section of my Windows settings. The startmenu entry itself can be removed by deleting the corresponding symlink at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js`

Answer (score 1):

On Window 10

1. Go to "Type here to search"
2. Type Install Additional Tools for
   Node.js
3. Right Click and select "open file location"
4. Delete the
   respective Command Line Program "Install Additional Tools for
   Node.js"

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation of the script

As mentioned elsewhere, [install_tools.bat](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/tools/msvs/install_tools/install_tools.bat) is the script that installs extra tools.

Keep in mind that this script will change over time. As of now (May 27, 2022), the script does the following:

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Start-Process '%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString(''https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1''));
choco upgrade -y python visualstudio2019-workload-vctools;
Read-Host ''Type ENTER to exit'' ' -Verb RunAs
```

The first section simply installs chocolatey (and it's from the offical install method on https://chocolatey.org/install#individual).

The next section installs two packages via chocolatey (`python` and `visualstudio2019-workload-vctools`).

The last section just waits for you to press enter.

### Answering your question

Assuming you don't use python or those VS tools, you can uninstall those additional tools by running

`choco uninstall python visualstudio2019-workload-vctools`

in a command line (cmd, powershell, etc). If you want, you can also [uninstall chocolatey afterwards](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/uninstallation).

Comment: This answer is most up to date. I have no idea do I really have to run that install.bat or not. But my PC already have Python, VS 2022 (that I think come with workload-vctools) installed. And my node JS apps run perfectly (most of them) except something like **pkg** that have problem with new JS module.

Comment: You don't need to run `install_tools.bat`, I only mentioned it because that's the script that adds the extra tools (so if people want to check the up-to-date code for it, they can). 
If you already use python and the VS tools you don't need to uninstall them.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little off topic, but I would like to ask if these are all the tools that come after the download is completed

[Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEtYz.png)

Comment: You need to raise this as a new question

Comment: Well, that means I'm going to make an account